# Ubuntu laptop keeps on connecting to advertising agencies

Tags: networking, ubuntu, google-chrome, ssl

I have just recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I found out that my laptop keeps connecting to digital advertising sites via port 443. I have noticed on different occasions that the laptop had established connections to AppNexus, RhythmOne, TremorVideo, etc. I'm sure I haven't visited these advertisement agency sites before.

1. Could this be an app feature in Ubuntu?
2. Are there commonly known contracts by Google and Ubuntu with digital advertisers to gather browsing data or computer usage?
3. Would it be ok to allow only Google Chrome and Firefox to connect to port 443?

Comment: Did you check the code of every page you visited? It is unfortunately quite frequent for pages to contain trackers. There are some privacy add-ons out there that block most of this traffic.

Comment: haven't though.

Comment: Perhaps you can look into [pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/) if you're worried about ads.